# Ajaxified Boolean Field toggles upon page load and refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a link_to that toggles a boolean field when clicked.  The problem is that it toggles when the page is refreshed and/or loaded.  Here is the code:

stories/show.html.erb

```
<div id="story">
  <%= render @story %>
</div>
```

_story.html.erb

```
<div id="storyShow">
    <% if story.user == current_user %> 
       <%= render 'stories/published', { :story => story } %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

stories_controller.rb

```
  def toggle_published
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
    @story.toggle!(:published)
  end
```

application_helper.rb

```
  def published_link_text(publishable)
    publishable.published? ? 'Published' : 'Un-Published'
  end
```

_published.html.erb

```
<% if story.published? %>
  <span id="publishedSwitchGreen" class="greenText">
    <%= link_to published_link_text(story), 
      toggle_published_story_path(story), :remote => true, :id => "story_publish#{story.id}" %>
  </span>

<% else %>

  <span id="publishedSwitchRed" class="redText">
    <%= link_to published_link_text(story), 
      toggle_published_story_path(story), :remote => true, :id => "story_publish#{story.id}" %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

toggle_published.js.erb

```
$("#story_publish<%= @story.id %>").text("<%= published_link_text(@story) %>");
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :stories do
    get 'toggle_published', :on => :member
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally pasted my toggle call in the Show action of the controller, so every time the story would show, it would toggle.